# Wish you happy new year or (a) happy new year

Tags: articles, christmas

I always use google with double quotes to get the answer for similar questions by looking at results number (assuming that the majority are correct), well, it is not the case here.
In these days, we intensively use the statement
Wish you happy New Year and Wish you Merry Christmas,
Well, I have noticed, even here, that some use (a) before happy and merry and some don't.
Which one is correct ?
Wish you Merry Christmas / Wish you a Merry Christmas for everybody here.

Comment: I wiish you *a* merry Christmas and *a* happy new year.

Comment: Either is correct.  With the "a" you're wishing that the event be merry/happy.  Without, you're effectively wishing a blessing on the person.  The difference is subtle and not important in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the article 'a' is correct.

**Wishing you a happy New Year!**

The Google Ngram Viewer is the correct tool for this job. [Have a look](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish%20you%20a%20merry%20christmas%2C%20wish%20you%20merry%20christmas&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwish%20you%20a%20merry%20christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwish%20you%20a%20merry%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwish%20you%20a%20Merry%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWish%20You%20a%20Merry%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWISH%20YOU%20A%20MERRY%20CHRISTMAS%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWish%20You%20A%20Merry%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwish%20you%20merry%20christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWish%20you%20merry%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwish%20you%20Merry%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwish%20you%20merry%20Christmas%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "We wish you a merry Christmas, and a happy New Year" occurs as a song lyric that is very familiar in America (and perhaps England as well?)  However, the "we wish you a" is dropped completely when giving an oral well-wishing. Generally, one simply  exclaims:

Merry Christmas!
and
Happy New Year!